# Convexity of variance

Tags: convex-analysis, variance

How can I prove the following function is convex? Is variance  concave or convex?

$$\psi (x)=\left(x_1-\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}\right)^2+ \left(x_2-\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}\right)^2+ \left(x_3-\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to see that this is convex is to note that it is the composition of a trivial quadratic function and an affine function (actually a linear one); that is, $\psi(x)=g(h(x))$, where
$$g:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \quad g(y) = y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^3$$
$$h:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3, \quad h(x)=(x_1-(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3,x_2-(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3,x_3-(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3)$$
It is of course easy to verify that $g$ is convex; its Hessian is twice the identity matrix. It truly is the prototypical multivariate convex function! And the composition of a convex function and an affine function is always convex.

EDIT: This is readily extended to all data sizes. That is, the function
$$\psi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \left( \textstyle \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right)\right)^2$$
is convex for any $n$. It is the composition of the trivially convex function
$$g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \quad g(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$$
and the affine function
$$h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n, \quad h(x) = (h_1(x),h_2(x),\dots,h_n(x)), \quad h_i(x) = x_i - \tfrac{1}{n}\textstyle\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$$
As the composition of a convex function and an affine function, it is convex. If you are getting an indefinite Hessian for $n>3$, as you suggest you are below, then your derivation is incorrect.

Comment: @ Michael thanks , I will check the derivation!

Comment: @Rezlen off the top of my head I think the Hessian is $2I-\tfrac{1}{n}\vec{1}\vec{1}^T$, but don't quote me on that---unless it is right, of course, in which case, quote away! :-)

Comment: you are right! My derivation was not correct! I used matlab and for any $n$ determinants are equal to zero; this is, it is  semidefinite so convex!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}ψ(x)=\frac23(2x_1-x_2-x_3)$$ and therefore $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}ψ(x)=\frac43, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1x_2}ψ(x)=-\frac23, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1x_3}ψ(x)=-\frac23$. 
So, due to symmetry the Hessian matrix is given by $$H=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_ix_j}ψ(x)\end{pmatrix}_{i,j}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac43&\frac{-2}3&\frac{-2}3\\
\frac{-2}3&\frac43&\frac{-2}3\\
\frac{-2}3&\frac{-2}3&\frac43\\
\end{pmatrix}=\frac23\begin{pmatrix} 2&-1&-1\\
-1&2&-1\\
-1&-1&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ which can be shown to be positive semidefinite (all leading principles are non-negative). So $ψ$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks @Stef ! In fact the function is $\psi (x)=min \sum _{i=1}^{n}(f_i(x_i)-\overline f(x))^2$

Comment: That's not a function, @Rezlen, that's an optimization problem.

Comment: @Stef and Michael ,  for $n>3$  the leading principle minors are not always positive. The 1st and 2nd are positive the 3rd is zero and the 4th is negative. Could you please help me to expand it for $n$ variables? And can I say the problem is positive semidefinite in this case?

Comment: @stef the leading principle minores for $n>3$ are negative. How can I prove it is a semidefinite ?

Comment: @Rezlen I am referring to your question, which is about $n=3$. $n>3$ is another question, do not ask it here in the comments.

Comment: @Stef thank you, can I add another quesition for $n>3$ here or should be a seperate quesition?

Comment: @Rezlen Your welcome. A separate question is the way to go :)

Comment: @Rezlen, variance is *always* convex in the data. If you're seeing something different for $n>3$ then your derivation is somehow wrong.